# Save a DataFrameWriter file to a human-readable format

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I am writing to an Amazon S3 bucket, but I'd like the file to have a more regular, human-readable name than `part-r-0-8asdifafasd98fu.csv` Is there an option or other method for this?

```
val savePath = "s3a://<...>"

val pdata = sqlContext.read.parquet(readPath + "/*")

val writer: DataFrameWriter[Row] = pdata.coalesce(1).write

writer.format("csv")
 .mode("overwrite")
 .option("header", "true")
 .option("delimiter", "|")
 .option("nullValue", "")
 .option("codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec")
 .save(savePath)
```

Comment: If your dataframe fits on the driver in 1 partittion then it doesn't need to the dataframe writer to put it on disk, which means that you can use the the aws s3 api to write it on s3

Comment: Thanks eliasah ; I am using the Qubole UI for this

Comment: coalesce(1) to create 1 partition is an anti-pattern in spark.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a way to have a more human readable format.  Each partition is written the S3 bucket in a separate part file.  In hadoop, we generally think of a dataset as a directory, and all the files in that directory are apart of a dataset.